# Why does `texreg` argument `scalebox` now throw an error when trying to render Rmarkdown pdf document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, texreg

I recently updated my OS, packages, RStudio and R and I tried to run a .Rmd file that worked fine before all the updates. When I ran the .Rmd, I was getting the an error at the end (after it reachd 100%) when trying to render a PDF document (seen below). After breaking up and running my Rmarkdown file piece by piece, I discovered the problem was the `scalebox =`  argument I used to produce a table with `texreg`.  I'm glad I discovered the issue but I am curious why scalebox does not work in an Rmarkdown document anymore. Reprex below (if you remove `scalebox = .75`, it will render just fine). Any thoughts?

````
title: "Reprex"
author: "Author"
date: ""
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
````

````
library(texreg)

df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100),
                 x = rnorm(100))

model <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)


```{r, results='asis'}
texreg(model,
       scalebox = .75)
````

```
output file: Reprex.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Reprex.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Reprex.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `scalebox = 0.75`, `texreg` needs to use the `graphicx` package.  It isn't set up to work with `knitr`, so it just outputs the `\usepackage{graphicx}` command ahead of the table, where it's illegal.  I imagine you're supposed to cut and paste the output into your document, with that line going into the preamble instead of the body.

To work around this design, just set `use.packages = FALSE` in the call to `texreg()`.  Since `knitr` already uses `graphicx`, that's sufficient.

If you get the same error with some package that `knitr` doesn't include (maybe you used `siunitx = TRUE`, which needs the `siunitx` package), then you'll need to display the result to figure out which package it needs, and then add that to the YAML of the document, e.g.

```
texreg(model,
       scalebox = .75, siunitx = TRUE)

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
...
```

which tells you to add this to your YAML, before running with `use.packages = FALSE`:

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: siunitx
```

and then the code chunk would be changed to

```
texreg(model,
       scalebox = .75, siunitx = TRUE, use.packages = FALSE)
```